# Clojure : How to define a function that prints a string without putting quotes to variable

Tags: clojure

I can do:

```
(defn hello [name] (println "Hello" name "!")) <br>
(hello "champ") -> Hello champ !
```

But how to change my function so I don't need to put quotes?

```
(hello champ) -> Hello champ !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a macro in order to achieve this:

```
(defmacro hello [nsym] `(println "Hello" ~(name nsym) "!"))
(hello world)
```

prints `Hello World !`

Edit: Correct the form so it won't mislead you. Thanks for kotarak's comment.

Comment: This will print the message at compile time, which is probably not the intent. This prints at runtime: `(defmacro hello [s] \`(println "Hello" ~(name s)))`

Answer (score 1):

This also works (using **str** instead of **name**):

```
(defmacro hello [nsym] `(println "Hello" ~(str nsym) "!"))
```